# What type of SSDs can be put in this laptop?

Tags: laptop, linux, ssd

I hope this isn't a silly question.

I've set my sights on a [Lenovo ThinkPad E570](https://www3.lenovo.com/au/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-edge/Thinkpad-E570/p/22TP2TEE570?menu-id=E570). If you click "Configure" on that link, you'll see that you can choose various options for the hard drive. I want a traditional hard disk drive for my data, as well as an SSD for the operating system. This is an allowed option on Lenovo's website, but:

1. I don't know if I want the SSD now, or whether I can wait to buy one later.
2. I don't know if I can buy an SSD at a cheaper price ($200 AUD from Lenovo for a 120GB SSD seems steep).

I'm not up to speed on SSD technology, and Lenovo sales were unhelpful in providing an adequate answer, so what type of SSD do I need? The first option on the site says "SATA3" while the second days "PCIe-NVME OPAL2".

**Non-essential Background Information**

A year ago I switched from macOS on a MacBook Pro to Fedora Linux. Running Linux directly on my Apple hardware proved difficult due to the dual graphics (I was unable to turn off the discrete graphics chip, which caused excessive heat and poor battery performance), so I've been running Linux in a Virtual Machine. However, it's now time for me to take the final step, sell my old MacBook Pro and purchase a Linux-friendly laptop, and most people highly recommend the ThinkPad range.

Comment: I suggest you make your question more general and include more of your requirements / expected workload. Hardware Recs generally works best when there is some freedom for the answerer to choose another option that may not have been considered, with the requirements specific enough to judge whether the answer is a good fit.

Comment: On SSDs: PCIe SSDs are simply faster. SATA III, nominally 6 Gbps, has a maximum transfer rate of 600 MB/s with 8b/10b encoding. Even the best SSDs are limited to ~500 MB/s sequential in real use. Mid end PCIe SSDs can easily push 2000 MB/s read and 1000 MB/s write. Of course, there's no  point getting the entry level SSDs in M.2 form factor, unless you're pressed for space. $200 for a 120 GB SSD is a massive ripoff. Shopping Express, for example, stocks the entry level *275 GB* [MX300](http://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/buy/crucial-mx300-275gb-sata-internal-ssd/CT275MX300SSD1) for $120.

Comment: The mid-end 250 GB [960 EVO](http://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/buy/samsung-960-evo-nvme-m.2-250gb-ssd/MZ-V6E250BW) is only $40 more. And yes, these are in AUD. Unless the SSD they're offering much better than the best on the market, it's a total ripoff.